# Deal card code error and better solution on dealing card

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*; 

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> shufflecard = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] cards = {"cA", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9", "cX", "cJ", "cQ", "cK", 
        "dA", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8", "d9", "dX", "dJ", "dQ", "dK", 
        "sA", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8", "s9", "sX", "sJ", "sQ", "sK", 
        "hA", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "hX", "hJ", "hQ", "hK"};
  
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
            shufflecard.add(cards[i]);
   }
          Collections.shuffle(shufflecard);
          //System.out.println(shufflecard);
        names.add("1");
        names.add("2");
        names.add("3");
        //int playersize =  names.size();
        //card Card = new card();
        card.cards();
        //System.out.println(names);
        //System.out.println(playersize);
        //String[] shucardarr = new card.shufflecard();
        //System.out.println(shufflecard);
        String player1 = names.get(0);
        String player2 = names.get(1);
        String player3 = names.get(2);
        ArrayList<String> player1card = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> player2card = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> player3card = new ArrayList<String>();

        boolean cardnoemp = true;

        while(cardnoemp){
            int i = 0;
            player1card.add(shufflecard.get(i));
            i++;
            player2card.add(shufflecard.get(i));
            i++;
            player3card.add(shufflecard.get(i));
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                shufflecard.remove(j);
            }
            if(shufflecard.isEmpty()){
                break;}

            }
    

        
        System.out.println(player1 + player1card);
        System.out.println(player2 + player2card);
        System.out.println(player3 + player3card);
    }}
```

This is my testing on my dealing card project
I use this to deal card to every player but I getjava.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2

```
        while(cardnoemp){
            int i = 0;
            player1card.add(shufflecard.get(i));
            i++;
            player2card.add(shufflecard.get(i));
            i++;
            player3card.add(shufflecard.get(i));
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                shufflecard.remove(j);
            }
            if(shufflecard.isEmpty()){
                break;}

            }
```

I have try reading on every questions I find online but I can't find the solution.

I need to use the card without separate suit and number and I can't find any suitable code online

If I can get a better solution on dealing card or solve this questions for me I will really appreciate . Thank you

Comment: What card is at index `j` before calling `shufflecard.remove(j)`?  What card is at index `j` right after you’ve called `shufflecard.remove(j)`?

Comment: `shufflecard.subList(0, 3).clear();`.

Comment: Just to point out, since, `Collections.shuffle` randomizes the order, you could just as easily give player 1 all their cards first; then player 2; then player 3. Dealing them out like you do "IRL" isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to deal the cards out in turn as you do "in real life".

`Collections.shuffle` randomizes the order, and ["All permutations occur with approximately equal likelihood"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-). This means that the set of cards you give each player is as likely if you deal them out "in real life" as if you just give each player a contiguous chunk of the shuffled cards.

(See also ["Does the order in which you deal cards from a shuffled deck matter?"](https://www.quora.com/Does-the-order-in-which-you-deal-cards-from-a-shuffled-deck-matter) on Quora).

So, an easier solution would be:

```
int third = shufflecard.size()/3;

// Give each player a third of the cards.
player1card.addAll(shufflecard.subList(0, third));
player2card.addAll(shufflecard.subList(third, 2*third));
player3card.addAll(shufflecard.subList(2*third, 3*third));

// Clear shufflecard, if you need to.
shufflecard.clear();
```

Comment: It work! Thanks for helping! I was just making logic to make it work like deal the card "in real life". and I forget this doesn't need to do like that! Thank you for help